# Does JS / jQuery have an available functions list on a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example in Ruby I can do this:

```
"some string".methods
```

And this would return all of the methods available for Class#String.

Can I do the same in JS/jQuery for selectors? example:

```
$('div[role="navigation"]').functions
console.log($('div[role="navigation"]').functions)
```

this returns 'undefined'

Comment: What do you need this for exactly? "Methods available for selectors" doesn't make much sense. The jQuery object always has the same methods regardless of the selector.

Comment: Just use the documentation https://api.jquery.com/

Comment: $.fn contains all those methods...

Comment: Just look at jquery documentation... Its like a single page, super easy to use.... There are only so many event handlers.. It's almost common sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using `console.log($('div[role="navigation"]'))` will show you all of the methods in most browsers.

Also `for (var i in $('div[role="navigation"]')) { if (typeof $('body')[i] == 'function') console.log(i) }` will list the methods out.

Answer (score 1):

`console.dir($('div[role="navigation"]'))` will print out a navigable tree.